# MySQL NFL QB rating - possible to set a minimum and maximum value if a sum adds up beyond a set range?

Tags: mysql, statistics

I am trying to calculate the NFL's quarterback rating in MySQL. I have my four categories, but I need to be able to set a limit on each of them. If it adds up to a negative number, it needs to be 0. And if it adds up higher than 2.375 I need it to be 2.375.

How can I add a minimum and maximum value to each of these four queries?

```
ROUND(((sum(case when pass_result='C' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when run_pass='P' then 1 else 0 end))-0.3)*5,3) AS 'Rule 1',
ROUND(((sum(gain)/sum(case when run_pass='P' then 1 else 0 end))-3)*0.25,3) AS 'Rule 2',
ROUND((sum(case when series_end='Touchdown' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when run_pass='P' then 1 else 0 end))*20,3) as 'Rule 3',
ROUND((2.375-(sum(case when pass_result='IN' then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when run_pass='P' then 1 else 0 end))*25),3) as 'Rule 4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
LEAST(GREATEST(ROUND(((SUM(pass_result='C') / SUM(run_pass='P'))-0.3)*5,3), 0), 2375) AS Rule1,
LEAST(GREATEST(ROUND(((SUM(gain)/SUM(run_pass='P'))-3)*0.25,3), 0), 2375) AS Rule2,
LEAST(GREATEST(ROUND((SUM(series_end='Touchdown') / SUM(run_pass='P'))*20,3), 0), 2375) AS Rule3,
LEAST(GREATEST(ROUND((2.375-(SUM(pass_result='IN')/SUM(run_pass='P'))*25),3), 0), 2375) AS Rule4
```

When you apply `GREATEST()` to a `x` value like:

```
GREATEST(x, 0)
```

then the if `x` is negative the result is `0`.

When you apply `LEAST()` to a `x` value like:

```
LEAST(x, 2375)
```

then the if `x` is greater than `2375` the result is `2375`.

I also simplified the code by using only the boolean expressions inside `SUM()` instead of the `CASE` expressions, because boolean expressions are evaluated as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

Comment: This works great! Taking out the "case when" will reduce my overall code considerably.